# Problem using std::binary_search and std::vector

Tags: c++

When I try this

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <short> g;
int main(){
    g.push_back(3);
    g.push_back(2);
    cout<<binary_search(g.begin(), g.end(), 2);
}
```

The output is `0`.

However, [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/#return) said that *std::binary_search* will return:

> `true` if an element equivalent to val is found, and `false` otherwise.

I think it must be `1` (or `true`) instead of `0`. Why doesn't it?

I'm sorry that I'm not good at English.

Comment: from your link `The elements in the range shall already be sorted according to this same criterion (operator< or comp), or at least partitioned with respect to val.`, your vector is not sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that your vector is not sorted before applying binary search.

Apply `std::sort(start_iterator, end_iterator);` before calling binary_search function;

P.S. the algorithm of `binary_search` returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comments about sorting are right. Here is a corrected version of your program that prints `true`:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
vector <short> g;
int main(){
    g.push_back(2);
    g.push_back(3);
    cout<< boolalpha << binary_search(g.begin(), g.end(), 2);
}
```